# Check if a Python script compiles using another Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation

I know `py_compile.compile("file.py")` will compile file.py.

But can I in that same code that runs that command somehow check if the compilation was successful or not?

I want to essentially have an if-condition depending on whether the compilation was a success or not. Is it possible using the py_compile module? Or is there something better I could use?

Comment: Have you tried with the [doraise](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/py_compile.html#py_compile.compile) option turned to true so it raises an exception if it fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import py_compile
try:
    py_compile.compile("file.py", doraise=True)
except py_compile.PyCompileError:
    print("Compilation failed!")
```

As always in Python, it is better to seek forgiveness than to ask permission.

Comment: Yup that's it. Is there something equivalent for `compileall.compile_dir`?

Comment: It doesn't appear there is, at first glance... It'd be relatively straightforward to use `py_compile` and write the recursion yourself (using eg. `os.walk`), but I'm not sure if `compileall` does other things than just compile.